# how to give different name for database other than PostgreSQL in Jenkins + Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

In server while deploying any project I want to give different database name in settings.py on django structure.**Where I have to change database name??**

My docker-compose.yml file as following..

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:

    image: postgres

  web:

    build: .

    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate  && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

    volumes:
      - .:/code

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    depends_on:

      - db
```

my database configuration is like this in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': 'postgres',

        'USER': 'postgres',

        'HOST': 'db',

        'PORT': 5432,

    }

}
```

**Where I have to change database name??**

Comment: Surely in the NAME attribute there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the POSTGRES_DB environment variable. From Postgres docker image docs:

> POSTGRES_DB This optional environment variable can be used to define a
>   different name for the default database that is created when the image
>   is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of
>   POSTGRES_USER will be used.

The docker-compose.yml file would be:

```
version: '3'

services:    
  db:    
    image: postgres
    env:
      POSTGRES_DB: <DATABASE NAME>
  web:    
    build: .    
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate  && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"    
    volumes:
      - .:/code    
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"    
    depends_on:    
      - db
```

-

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': '<DATABASE NAME>',

        'USER': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',

    'PORT': 5432,

  }

}
```

Comment: I am using different database like this in Django settings.py 

DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': 'postgres',

        'USER': 'postgres',

        'HOST': 'db',

        'PORT': 5432,

    }

}

Comment: Just added the config.py file